# Elements Jiggling/Vibrating As Other Values Change With Input

Tags: html, css, input, output, containers

I have sliders and some output boxes to display the values of these sliders. As the user moves the sliders and the values change, the rest of the page moves/jiggles to accommodate the new (very slight) increase in size of the values. What's the best way to prevent this? I've tried using a container with some padding but then this just "adds on" to the value size and everything keeps jiggling.

Here's it happening in action with the sliders on top: www.cherb.co.uk/map

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that can work. In your CSS add display:block to class slider.

```
.slider {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 90px;
    height: 10px;
    background: white;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply - this did do the trick but now I'm struggling with getting the output and slider on the same line without the jiggle (i.e. value just to the left of the slider). As blocks they seem set on having their own line - I've updated cherb.co.uk/map again to demonstrate. cheers!